# Is there a error at page 566 of Atkins Physical Chemistry?

Tags: physical-chemistry, erratum

At page 556 I found this question being analyzed and the rate law is provided.
However, when I apply steady state approximation, I can't find the result without the factor 2. 
Is it me being wrong?

[image]

Comment: Edition number?

Comment: I guess I'm a dolt, but I don't understand "I can't find the result without the coefficient 2."

Comment: It's edition 11.

Answer (score 5):

The factor of 2 originates from the definition of $k_b$ (I thought it was an error, but it turns out IUPAC guidelines lead to its presence).

If $k_\mathrm{a}' \gg k_\mathrm{b}[\ce{O2}]$ and defining

$$K_\mathrm{a} = \frac{k_\mathrm{a}}{k_\mathrm{a}'}$$

it follows from the equation posted in the OP that

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{NO2}]}{\mathrm{d}t} = 2k_\mathrm{b}K_\mathrm{a}[\ce{NO}]^2[\ce{O2}]$$

However, starting from scratch we *could* write that

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{NO2}]}{\mathrm{d}t} = k_\mathrm{b}[\ce{N2O2}][\ce{O2}]$$

(this is not the standard IUPAC convention however).
Then, if

$$K_\mathrm{a} = \frac{k_\mathrm{a}}{k_\mathrm{a}'} = \frac{[\ce{N2O2}]}{[\ce{NO}]^2}$$

it follows that

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{NO2}]}{\mathrm{d}t} = k_\mathrm{b}K_\mathrm{a}[\ce{NO}]^2[\ce{O2}]$$

and the factor of $2$ is not there. In the fourth version of Atkins' book (which I parallel in this derivation from "scratch") the factor of 2 is missing, but in that book the analysis does not proceed by dissecting the full rate law before imposing the pre-equilibrium approximation. The OP presumably sources a later version of the book. As noted in a comment, IUPAC guidelines call for incorporation of that factor of 2. One should write

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{NO2}]}{\mathrm{d}t} = 2k_\mathrm{b}[\ce{N2O2}][\ce{O2}]$$ because that step of the reaction reads $$\ce{N2O2 + O2->2NO2}$$ The stoichiometric factor of 2 means two moles of 
$\ce{NO2}$ are produced for every mole of reaction.

Comment: Um. It sort of depends on how you define the rate equation for the third reaction in the series; if you define it instead as $$\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{NO2}]}{\mathrm{d}t} = 2k'_\mathrm{b}[\ce{N2O2}][\ce{O2}]$$ then you end up with the correct factor of 2. That simply necessitates that my rate constant $k'_\mathrm b = k_\mathrm b / 2$. In fact, this is more in line with IUPAC: https://goldbook.iupac.org/html/R/R05156.html There's a question about this on SE, but I don't have the time to find it now.

Comment: @orthocresol totally right...

Comment: @NightWriter I think it would be helpful if you edited your answer to indicate more clearly that including the factor of 2 is in fact the standard convention and not an error, rather than just acknowledging that at the end.

Comment: @orthocresol [This one](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/66253/what-is-the-correct-way-to-calculate-the-rate-constant-for-the-reaction-of-no-an)?

Comment: @hBy2Py I was thinking of this one https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/38167/16683, but yours fits as well and I wouldn't be surprised if there are even more.

Comment: @orthocresol Ah, yeah, yours looks rather more canonical and detailed than mine.